# How to show the name of document in the dock instead of the application name?

Tags: gnome, dock

When I have multiple open pdfs (for example), I'd like to gloss over the Okular icon and it to show the name of the document. Instead they all just show "okular" which becomes annoying to then click through all of them to see which is the right one. Is there a way to make it show the name of the document when having the cursor over the icon?

Here is a photo of what I mean:

[image]

The application icons are in the dock and when you gloss over a pdf file that is open (doesn't matter which program) it shows only the name of the program. So you move the cursor over the program and it just shows "okular" in my case. When I have multiple pdfs open it becomes cumbersome to figure out which one I want to open since they all show "okular".

Using GNOME 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Is this about the default Ubuntu desktop? Where is this Okular icon located? In your taskbar?  In a dock?

Comment: @vanadium the application icons are in the dock and when you gloss over say a pdf file that is open (doesn't matter which program) it shows only the name of the program. So you move the cursor over the program and it just says "okular" in my case. When I have multiple pdfs open it becomes cumbersome to figure out which one I want to open since they all say "okular".

Comment: Please use "edit" to add this clarification to the question, where everybody will see it. Also provide information on your current desktop ( the command `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` may tell) and eventually your Ubuntu version (`lsb_release -a`) although the latter will probably less important. The answer, however, will depend very much on the desktop environment you use.

Comment: I added it but I already had a gnome tag to let people know it was gnome.

Comment: If you have multiple documents open, it sounds as if you have multiple icons in the dock? Can you describe more specifically and in detail what you see and what you wish to see?

Comment: You're right a visual would have been better. I thought about doing it at the beginning but I uploaded a photo to the question

Comment: This does not look like stock Ubuntu. What customizations did you do? By default, multiple documents in the same program would be represented by a single icon.

Comment: That's stock Ubuntu with GNOME. For other programs like Firefox, Chrome, Thunderbird etc. the same programs do bundle together but for example pdf documents it doesn't bundle. I think I find a better solution. I've been trying out Dash to Panel and it is seems much more advanced than the Dock and has a lot of settings to adjust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ubuntu dock doesn't allow for this in GNOME (could be different for different desktop environments). The Ubuntu dock is based off of the [Dash to Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) extension and this extension also doesn't allow for this.

But this can be solved by using a different option: [Dash to Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/). It provides a lot more options than Dash to Dock. It's a bit different of a workflow, as the Dock and the top bar are meshed into one, but it does what is asked in the question.

You can set up Dash to Panel as follows:

- Go to the extension's settings in Tweaks and click on the *Behavior* tab. The last option is *Ungroup applications*. Make sure it's ON. You can also click the additional settings on *Ungroup applications*.
- Also have a look at *Show window previews on hover* on the same tab. This option will let you see a preview of the program before clicking on it.